# SignalR get bearer token on Server

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

For a project, I have a C# asp.net core server and an Angular web client application. I was following the [SignalR documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=dotnet) on bearer tokens. It states that in order to give the authentication token, you can pass it as follows (copy-paste of the documentation).

```
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/chathub", {
        accessTokenFactory: () => {
            // Get and return the access token.
            // This function can return a JavaScript Promise if asynchronous
            // logic is required to retrieve the access token.
        }
    })
    .build();
```

But now, I would like to extract this specific token on my C# server. The problem is, I can't find it anywhere. only the `Context` of type `HubCallerContext` is provided when a user connects in the method `public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()` or when a user invokes a method himself. But this `Context`does not supply the given authentication token. How could I extract this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to get the token in the hub method, you could refer to below codes to get it.

```
 var accessToken = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["access_token"];
```